# Pydantic root_validator - ok to use once for entire model, instead of individual validators?

Tags: python, pandas, validation, data-modeling, pydantic

I am using Pydantic to create a Timeseries model based on pandas Timestamp (`start`, `end`) and Timedelta (`period`) objects.  The model will be used by a small data analysis program with a number of configurations/scenarios.

I need to instantiate and validate aspects of the Timeseries model based on two bool (`include_end_period`, `allow_future`) and one optional int (`max_periods`) config params.  I then need to derive three new fields (`timezone`, `total_duration`, `total_periods`) and perform some additional validations.

Due to several instances of needing to use one value when validating another, I was unable to achieve the desired result with the typical `@validator` methods.  In particular, I would often get a missing KeyError instead of an expected ValueError.  The best solution I've found is to instead create one long `@root_validator(pre=True)` method.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, root_validator, conint
from pandas import Timestamp, Timedelta


class Timeseries(BaseModel):
    start: Timestamp
    end: Timestamp
    period: Timedelta
    include_end_period: bool = False
    allow_future: bool = True
    max_periods: conint(gt=0, strict=True) | None = None
    
    # Derived values, do not pass as params
    timezone: str | None
    total_duration: Timedelta
    total_periods: conint(gt=0, strict=True)
    
    class Config:
        extra = 'forbid'
        validate_assignment = True
    
    
    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def _validate_model(cls, values):
        
        # Validate input values
        if values['start'] > values['end']:
            raise ValueError('Start timestamp cannot be later than end')
        if values['start'].tzinfo != values['end'].tzinfo:
            raise ValueError('Start, end timezones do not match')
        if values['period'] <= Timedelta(0):
            raise ValueError('Period must be a positive amount of time')
        
        # Set timezone
        timezone = values['start'].tzname()
        if 'timezone' in values and values['timezone'] != timezone:
            raise ValueError('Timezone param does not match start timezone')
        values['timezone'] = timezone
        
        # Set duration (add 1 period if including end period)
        total_duration = values['end'] - values['start']
        if values['include_end_period']:
            total_duration += values['period']
        if 'total_duration' in values and values['total_duration'] != total_duration:
            error_context = ' + 1 period (included end period)' if values['include_end_period'] else ''
            raise ValueError(f'Duration param does not match end - start timestamps{error_context}')
        values['total_duration'] = total_duration
        
        # Set total_periods
        periods_float: float = values['total_duration'] / values['period']
        if periods_float != int(periods_float):
            raise ValueError('Total duration not divisible by period length')
        total_periods = int(periods_float)
        if 'total_periods' in values and values['total_periods'] != total_periods:
            raise ValueError('Total periods param does not match')
        values['total_periods'] = total_periods
        
        # Validate future
        if not values['allow_future']:
            # Get current timestamp to floor of period (subtract 1 period if including end period)
            max_end: Timestamp = Timestamp.now(tz=values['timezone']).floor(freq=values['period'])
            if values['include_end_period']:
                max_end -= values['period']
            if values['end'] > max_end:
                raise ValueError('End period is future or current (incomplete)')
        
        # Validate derived values
        if values['total_duration'] < Timedelta(0):
            raise ValueError('Total duration must be positive amount of time')
        if values['max_periods'] and values['total_periods'] > values['max_periods']:
            raise ValueError('Total periods exceeds max periods param')
        
        return values
```

Instantiating the model in the happy case, using all config checks:

```
start = Timestamp('2023-03-01T00:00:00Z')
end = Timestamp('2023-03-02T00:00:00Z')
period = Timedelta('5min')

try:
    ts = Timeseries(start=start, end=end, period=period,
                    include_end_period=True, allow_future=False, max_periods=10000)
    print(ts.dict())
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e)
```

Output:

```
"""
{'start': Timestamp('2023-03-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
 'end': Timestamp('2023-03-02 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
 'period': Timedelta('0 days 00:05:00'),
 'include_end_period': True,
 'allow_future': False,
 'max_periods': 10000,
 'timezone': 'UTC',
 'total_duration': Timedelta('1 days 00:05:00'),
 'total_periods': 289}
"""
```

Here I believe all my validation is working as expected, and delivers the expected ValueErrors instead of less helpful KeyErrors.  **Is this approach reasonable?**  It seems to go against the typical/recommended approach, and the `@root_validator` documentation is quite brief compared to that of the `@validator`.

I am also unsatisfied that I need to list the derived values (`timezone`, `total_duration`, `total_periods`) at the top of the model.  This implies they can/should be passed when instantiating, and requires extra logic in my validator script to check if they were passed, and if they match the derived values.  By omitting them they would not benefit from the default validation of type, constraints, etc., and would force me to change the config to `extra='allow'`.  I would appreciate any tips on how to improve this.

Thank you!

Comment: A few things immediately stick out to me: If you have what you call "derived fields", that already implies redundancy and in fact it seems you do not _want_ a user to pass e.g. `timezone` explicitly. It is trivially derived from the `start` value. (Same for the other "derived" fields.) My question is why do you even want them as **fields**? Why not just define methods (and/or properties) on your model for those? IMO they don't _need_ validation since they would be derived when needed from already validated "actual" fields. Or is it a performance issue?

Comment: Also, this is a minor thing, shouldn't [`Timestamp.floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html) only accept a `str` type argument for `freq`? You are passing a `Timedelta`, when you caluclate `max_end`.

Comment: In general I would say, the "best" approach highly depends on what schema exactly you **want at the end**. You should always start by defining the model in terms of what you want "at the other end" of the parsing and validation process and **not** in terms of the raw data you might get at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts @DaniilFajnberg! It is not a performance issue, I'm just trying to do the validation in the model rather than performing any validation logic outside of Pydantic. Ignoring `timezone` which as you point out, can be easily obtained from `start` or `end` Timestamp, `total_duration` and `total_periods`are indeed derived values which will be used by other parts of my program. Passing these in when instantiating the model sort of defeats the purpose, and I would like to validate that `total_periods` does not exceed any configured `max_periods` param.

Comment: It's an interesting point about `Timestamp.floor`. From testing, it seems that `freq='5min'` is treated the same as `freq=Timedelta('5min')`, and I did find one area of documentation that supports this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.frequencies.to_offset.html My guess is this feature is missing from the `floor` area of the documentation?

Comment: In general I was just hoping to learn if this type of approach with a single `root_validator` was common/acceptable, since I couldn't find any examples of this in documentation or existing SE questions.  And I was also hoping to remove the confusion of being able to pass in my 'derived values' at instantiation, but still perform the validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing purposes it is usually a good idea *not* to have such large functions. Even if you want to go for the `root_validator` approach, you can (and IMO should) still divide up the logic into distinct, semantically sensible methods.

But I would suggest a slightly different approach altogether. Since `timezone`, `total_duration` and `total_periods` are derived from other fields and that process is not very expensive, I would define properties for those instead of having them as fields.

This has the advantage that you don't need to compute their values in advance, which means you don't need the `pre=True` approach and can utilize previously validated field values in *field-specific* validators.

Root validators still make sense, when you really need to ensure that many distinct fields taken together follow a certain logic.

Here is what I propose:

```py
from collections.abc import Mapping
from typing import Any

from pandas import Timedelta, Timestamp
from pydantic import BaseModel, conint, root_validator, validator

AnyMap = Mapping[str, Any]


class Timeseries(BaseModel):
    start: Timestamp
    end: Timestamp
    period: Timedelta
    include_end_period: bool = False
    allow_future: bool = True
    max_periods: conint(gt=0, strict=True) | None = None

    @validator("end")
    def ensure_end_consistent_with_start(
        cls,
        v: Timestamp,
        values: AnyMap,
    ) -> Timestamp:
        val_start: Timestamp = values["start"]
        if v < val_start:
            raise ValueError("Start timestamp cannot be later than end")
        if val_start.tzinfo != v.tzinfo:
            raise ValueError("Start, end timezones do not match")
        return v

    @validator("period")
    def ensure_period_is_positive(cls, v: Timedelta) -> Timedelta:
        if v <= Timedelta(0):
            raise ValueError("Period must be a positive amount of time")
        return v

    @validator("period")
    def ensure_period_divides_duration(
        cls,
        v: Timedelta,
        values: AnyMap,
    ) -> Timedelta:
        duration: float = (values["end"] - values["start"]) / v
        if int(duration) != duration:
            raise ValueError("Total duration not divisible by period length")
        return v

    @root_validator
    def ensure_end_is_allowed(cls, values: AnyMap) -> AnyMap:
        if values["allow_future"]:
            return values
        val_period: Timedelta = values["period"]
        val_end: Timestamp = values["end"]
        max_end = Timestamp.now(tz=val_end.tzname()).floor(freq=val_period)
        if values["include_end_period"]:
            max_end -= val_period
        if val_end > max_end:
            raise ValueError("End period is future or current (incomplete)")
        return values

    @root_validator
    def ensure_num_periods_allowed(cls, values: AnyMap) -> AnyMap:
        periods = int((values["end"] - values["start"]) / values["period"])
        if values["include_end_period"]:
            periods += 1
        if values["max_periods"] and periods > values["max_periods"]:
            raise ValueError("Total periods exceeds max periods param")
        return values

    @property
    def timezone(self) -> str | None:
        return self.start.tzname()

    @property
    def total_duration(self) -> Timedelta:
        total_duration = self.end - self.start
        if self.include_end_period:
            total_duration += self.period
        return total_duration

    @property
    def total_periods(self) -> int:
        return int(self.total_duration / self.period)
```

I guess it is a matter of personal preference, when to switch from field validators to root validators. For example, you could argue `ensure_period_divides_duration` should be a root validator since it uses the values of three fields.

Your example data of course works with this model as well.

One thing to note is that the range constraint on `total_periods` is redundant anyway, when you validate that `end` is after `start` (and that `period` evenly divides the total duration).

You could also argue that even something as simple as `total_duration` should not be a property. In that case you could make it a method called `get_total_duration`.

But if you have those "derived" fields, you'll always run into the issue of having to check that whatever was passed by the user is consistent with the rest of the data.

I believe most of this headache will be gone, once Pydantic v2 drops, which promises [**computed fields**](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/4648) (see the [plan for v2](https://docs.pydantic.dev/blog/pydantic-v2/#other-improvements)).

Comment: Thank you Daniil for this alternate solution! I agree this looks cleaner and is much easier to test! But I do think the 'computed fields' in Pydantic V2 seems closer to what I was originally hoping for - thanks for calling this out.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `AnyMap = Mapping[str, Any]` is only used here for typing of the `values` object?  I'm unsure why this is necessary/recommended if `type(values)` returns `dict`?  Thanks

Comment: @sha2fiddy In case of `root_validator` methods, the `values` object is actually of a special `GetterDict` type. I chose `Mapping` because it is a supertype of both that and the normal `dict`.